# How to type an array with classes in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an app that initializes by running its method `.init(params)` like this:

```
app.init([TopBar, StatusBar, MainArea]);
```

Where `TopBar`, `StatusBar` and `MainArea` are classes, not instances of classes. Each of these classes implements the same interface `IComponent`.

I want to instantiate objects from the passed classes in the `.init(params)` method, like this:

```
init(params: IComponent[]): void {
    params.map(function (component) {
        let comp = new component();
        this.components[comp.constructor.name] = comp;
    }, this);
```

The issue is that as these are not instance, TypeScript doesn't know their types and throws an error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(typeof TopBar | typeof StatusBar |
>   typeof MainArea)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'IComponent[]'.

How do I fix the code so that I could pass an array of classes that implement some interface to a method?

Comment: Why not use a factory function instead of trying to use new on the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [working typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20TopBar%09implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20StatusBar%20implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20MainArea%20%20implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20a%20type%20we%20want%20to%20be%20passed%20into%20INIT%20as%20an%20array%0D%0Atype%20InterfaceComponent%20%3D%20(typeof%20TopBar%20%7C%20typeof%20StatusBar%20%7C%20typeof%20MainArea)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20components%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%20%3A%20IComponent%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20init(params%3A%20(InterfaceComponent)%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params.map((component)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20comp%20%3D%20new%20component()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.components%5Bcomp.constructor%5B%22name%22%5D%5D%20%3D%20comp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Ax.init(%5BTopBar%2C%20StatusBar%2C%20MainArea%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(x.components))%0D%0A) (run it to get alert with result)

what we need is to create a custom **`type InterfaceComponent`**. That will be expected as an array of the `init()` method

```
interface IComponent { }
class TopBar    implements IComponent { }
class StatusBar implements IComponent { }
class MainArea  implements IComponent { }

// this is a type we want to be passed into INIT as an array
type InterfaceComponent = (typeof TopBar | typeof StatusBar | typeof MainArea);

class MyClass {

  components: {[key:string] : IComponent } = {};

  init(params: (InterfaceComponent)[]): void {
    params.map((component) => {
        let comp = new component();
        this.components[comp.constructor["name"]] = comp;
    }, this);
  }
}

let x = new MyClass();
x.init([TopBar, StatusBar, MainArea])

alert(JSON.stringify(x.components))
```

Check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20TopBar%09implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20StatusBar%20implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20MainArea%20%20implements%20IComponent%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20a%20type%20we%20want%20to%20be%20passed%20into%20INIT%20as%20an%20array%0D%0Atype%20InterfaceComponent%20%3D%20(typeof%20TopBar%20%7C%20typeof%20StatusBar%20%7C%20typeof%20MainArea)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20components%3A%20%7B%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%20%3A%20IComponent%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20init(params%3A%20(InterfaceComponent)%5B%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20params.map((component)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20comp%20%3D%20new%20component()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.components%5Bcomp.constructor%5B%22name%22%5D%5D%20%3D%20comp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Ax.init(%5BTopBar%2C%20StatusBar%2C%20MainArea%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(x.components))%0D%0A)

Comment: This is the most elegant solution, thanks! Though, it means, that, if I have a lot of components, like 100+, will I have to add them all to the type `InterfaceComponent`?

Comment: Well, hard to say without deep dive... to follow the above approach.. we would need to extend it ... and that is not ok for 100+. Some Factory method, working with passed unknown type (not so type safe) would be more proper way to go, I'd say...  `var instance = Object.create(objectType.prototype);
            instance.constructor.apply(instance, constructorParameters);`

Comment: The inheritance is the wrong way round - InterfaceComponent needs to know all the classes that implement it, surely that's not a good thing?

Comment: oh! the `typeof` is the main magic here! I didn't even need the interface - `: Set<typeof MyBaseModel>` was enough! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Typescript supports Class Type Generics ([TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)). Their example is:

```
function create<T>(c: {new(): T; }): T {
    return new c();
}
```

Which says "Pass into my `create` method a class that when constructed will return the type T that I want". This signature will prevent you from trying to pass in any class type that isn't of type T.

This is close to what we want, we just need to adjust for it being an array of items and items of your `IComponent`.

```
public init(components: {new(): IComponent;}[]): void {
    // at this point our `components` variable is a collection of
    // classes that implement IComponent

    // for example, we can just new up the first one;
    var firstComponent = new components[0]();
}, this);
```

With the method signature, we can now use it like

```
app.init([TopBar, StatusBar, MainArea]);
```

Where we pass in the array of types that implement `IComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question: this is how you do it:

```
interface IComponent { something(): void; }
class TopBar implements IComponent { something() { console.log('in TopBar'); }}
class StatusBar implements IComponent { something() { console.log('in StatusBar'); }}
class MainArea implements IComponent { something() { console.log('in MainArea'); }}

interface ComponentClass {
    new(): IComponent;
}

const components: { [name: string]: IComponent } = {};

function init(params: ComponentClass[]) {
    params.map((component) => {
        let comp = new component();
        components[component.name] = comp;
    });
}

init([TopBar, StatusBar, MainArea]);

for (const c in components) {
    console.log('Component: ' + c);
    components[c].something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could specify the type of `comp` as `InterfaceComponent`.

```
var comp: InterfaceComponent = new component();
this.components[comp.constructor.name] = comp;
```

Comment: The last thing I want to do with TypeScript is assign everything's type to any.

Comment: How about assigning it InterfaceComponent

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory method instead. The declaration is a bit clumsy but the idea works:

```
interface InterfaceComponent {
    name: string;
}

class TopBar implements InterfaceComponent {
    name: string;
}

class StatusBar implements InterfaceComponent {
    name: string;
}

class MainArea implements InterfaceComponent {
    name: string;
}

interface InterfaceComponentFactory {
    create: () => InterfaceComponent;
}

function init(params: InterfaceComponentFactory[]): void {
    params.map(function (component) {
        let comp = component.create();
        this.components[comp.name] = comp;
    }, this);
}

init([{ create: () => new TopBar() }, { create: () => new StatusBar() }, { create: () => new MainArea() }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two different ways you can create types for this situation:

```
// Interface style:
export default interface IConstructor<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

// Union Type style:
export type ConstructorUnion<T> = new(...args : any[]) => T;
```

So this is how it would look with the `IConstructor` type:

```
interface IComponent { }
class TopBar implements IComponent { }
class StatusBar implements IComponent { }
class MainArea { }

class App {
  public components: { [key: string]: IComponent } = {};

  public init(params: IConstructor<IComponent>[]): void {
    params.forEach((Component: IConstructor<IComponent>) => {
      const comp: IComponent = new Component();

      this.components[comp.constructor.name] = comp;
    });
  }
}

const app = new App();

app.init([TopBar, StatusBar, MainArea]);

console.clear();
console.log(app);
```

Here is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-type-an-array-with-classes-in-typescript?file=index.ts